# MySQL - How to join those tables to get the correct result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying for a couple of hours to figure this out, but it still does not work..

I have 2 tables:

- Prices
- Sales

The records are something like:

Prices

```
product_name   price
--------------------
Milk           0.80
Cheese         1.00
Bread          1.50
```

Sales

```
customer_id  product_name  number_purchases
-------------------------------------------
15           Milk          2
15           Cheese        1
2            Butter        2
2            Candy         4
80           Bread         1
...
...
15           Bread          2
15           Milk           1
```

The sales are tracked per week, a customer can occur multiple times in the database with a purchase of the same goods (like in the example customer 15 buys milk twice a week, so customer 15 bought 3 packs of milk.

I want to get for a certain customer: 
Each product he/she bought, with the corresponding total number of purchases of that product, and the corresponding price of the product.

This is what I have so far without errors:

```
SELECT product_name, SUM(number_purchases)
FROM sales S
WHERE customer_id = 80
GROUP BY product_name;
```

But when I want to add some lines to the code, to get the corresponding prices too, it does not work. One of the things I tried:

```
SELECT product_name, SUM(number_purchases), price
FROM sales S, prices P
WHERE S.product_name = P.productname
AND customer_id = 80
GROUP BY product_name;
```

Is this not possible in only one query or do I miss something?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does not work is not much to go on.Probably in your second query you need to specify the table alias->`S.product_name` because it exists in both tables so its ambiguous.

Comment: plesase do a fiddle example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aliases

```
SELECT s.product_name, SUM(number_purchases), price
FROM sales S, prices P
WHERE S.product_name = P.productname
AND customer_id = 80
GROUP BY s.product_name;
```

DBMS - doesn't know wich product_name get

P.S. and I think u have to add price in group by

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. Using s.productname solved part of the problem, adding price in GROUP BY solved the other part of the problem. It works now!

Answer (score 3):

Your last query is grouping by `customer_id`.  Try changing this to `product_name`:

```
SELECT S.product_name, SUM(S.number_purchases), P.price
FROM sales S, prices P
WHERE S.product_name = P.product_name
AND S.customer_id = 80
GROUP BY S.product_name;
```

You should also *never* use commas in the `from` clause.  Instead use explicit joins as in your first example and aggregate on `price` as well (or move `price` to the `group by` clause):

```
SELECT S.product_name, SUM(S.number_purchases), sum(P.price) total_price
FROM sales S join
     prices P
     ON S.product_name = P.product_name
WHERE S.customer_id = 80
GROUP BY S.product_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding that quick.
I don't know why, but that is a mistake in my post. I tried to GROUP BY product_name instead of customer_id, but I get the error:
columnname 'product_name' is in more than one table in the FROM list.

Comment: @MarkM `S.product_name`

Comment: @MarkM . . . Your OP has `product_name` in one table and `productname` in the other.  I think both should be `product_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You query should be:

```
SELECT product_name, SUM(number_purchases), price
FROM sales S, prices P
WHERE S.product_name = P.productname
AND customer_id = 80
GROUP BY P.productname;
```